# Firefox CSS Against me??

Tags: css, firefox, printing

I am a Programmer and not a Designer. 
My boss asked me to modify the print.css 
I modified the print.css 10 Hours, nothing nothing and nothing happened.
If with IE everything looks good, in FF it looks horrible.
If with FF everything looks good, in IE it looks horrible.
What did i wrong?
Pls have a look at this website
www.trigami.com
Thanks

Comment: looks pretty much the same in IE8, FF3.5, and Chrome3

Comment: No it doesnt. 
Do you have sunglases or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the CSS to look good for each individual browser, just serve different CSS files based on which browser is being used. You can check for IE/CSS on the server, or use a client-side trick.

If you are having specific problems with your CSS - you should ask questions about them, but asking people to "figure out why your site looks horrible" isn't likely to get you much help.

Comment: Hy, does anyone have universal print.css which can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [validating your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.html.en) and [your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You might start by using a reset CSS, there's this widely from [meyerweb.com](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or the Yahoo option in [YUI site](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/), this way you'll reset the nasty defaults from the browsers. After using reset CSS I've found it's easier to get your site running the same in every browser

Comment: I did that but it didnt work.
i think there is a problem with the .alt which the position is not set.
But i also set .a { position:absolute;} i also testet with ; fixed,static

Comment: OK then I recommend you to post a narrower question explaining your particular case ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to help you if you don't give any details.

But it sounds like you've bee hit by the [box model problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)